# Capturing an image from a Running VirtualBox VM - powered on

Tags: virtualbox

I have a production server, no way to stop this server, but
I want to capture an image or clone of this server without stopping it.
I use a type 2 hypervisor - VirtualBox

I could not find any solutions related to this issue, so I hope anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

You can create a snapshot when a VM is either on, saved, or off. I’ll demonstrate the process of taking a snapshot when the VM is powered on

Once the machine is up and running click Machine | Take Snapshot. A new window will appear, prompting you for a name and a description of the snapshot. It’s important to fill out the name and description because you might take multiple snapshots, and you don’t want to get those snapshots confused; plus, this allows you to restore back to multiple points in the configuration.

Please check this reference : [How to use snapshots in VirtualBox](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-use-snapshots-in-virtualbox/)